# Tkinter delete all moving objects at defined coords

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have got some shapes and a bunch of( thousands of ) moving lines. Lines are created every time and they move through downward. I want to delete them if their top coords is 200. But when I have tried this the all canvas stops the moving ( other shapes and all lines stop and all lines deleted). I need help here. I want that: The lines will be deleted at certain X coords, meanwhile the creation and move of the the lines will keep going on dynamically without any process stops or closed.

```py
class Flow:
    def __init__(self, tph, color, canvas):
        self.flows = []
        self.tph = tph
        self.color = color
        self.Xspeed = 10
        self.Yspeed = 0
        self.canvas = canvas

    def create_flow(self):
        for i in range(self.tph):
            self.flow = self.canvas.create_line(550, 50, 500, 52, fill=self.color, width=2)
            self.flows.append(self.flow)

        return self.flows
    
    def move_flow(self):
        for self.flow in self.flows:
            self.canvas.move(self.flow, self.Xspeed - randint(10, 30), self.Yspeed + randint(10, 20))

flow = Flow(10, "#976C3D", canvas)

def animate():
    flow.create_flow()
    flow.move_flow()

    canvas.after(100, animate)

animate()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by delete ? Hide ?

Comment: remove from the canvas

Comment: You can add `if self.canvas.bbox(self.flow)[1] > 200` in your `move_flow` function. Then to delete the sprite just use `self.canvas.delete(self.flow)`. You will also have to remove it from your list

Comment: it is stopping the program. all objects are stopping move

Comment: *"delete them if their top coords is 200"* which is talking about the y-coordinate, however *"The lines will be deleted at certain X coords"* is talking about the x-coordinate.  So which one do you want actually? If it is talking about the y-coordinate, do you mean that you want to delete the line when its y-coordinate > 200? If it is talking about x-coordinate, do you mean the line will be deleted if its x-coordinate < 200?

Comment: that X mean variable not X coord. In my case the problem is lines are creating continuously. When I tried to take one of thems coord it doesn't keep track it, it jumps new created lines coords. Its going like that to the infinity.

Comment: Then do you want to remove lines with top y-coordinate > 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove lines with y-coordinate > 200, you can modify `move_flow()` as below:

```py
def move_flow(self):
    for flow in self.flows:
        coords = self.canvas.coords(flow)
        if coords[1] > 200:  # top y > 200
            self.canvas.delete(flow) # delete the canvas line item
            self.flows.remove(flow) # delete the item in self.flows as well
        else:
            self.canvas.move(flow, self.Xspeed-randint(10, 30), self.Yspeed+randint(10, 20))
```